# What hardware support needs to be present for USB Type-C alternate modes?

Tags: usb

Is support for USB Type-C alternate modes (such as MHL and DisplayPort) entirely the responsibility of the USB controller, or is the responsibility shared among other devices? For example, if I wanted to use a USB-C-to-HDMI cable to connect my computer to my monitor, would I just have to get a USB add-on card that supports the MHL alternate mode, or would I need a graphics card that has its own USB-C port? Similarly, if a motherboard has a USB-C port on it that doesn't support any alternate modes today, will any hardware additions or BIOS updates ever make that port support them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For USB-C alternate modes to work, there has to be a physical connection from the alternate signal source to the corresponding pins of the USB-C port.

Unlike some older USB video adapters that actually include a small external GPU and transmit the display content as USB data, USB-C alt modes really just patch through a physical signal that the USB controller doesn't even understand. The controller is just used for negotiating what that alternate signal will be and which of the 1-4 possible connections will be used.

For discrete graphics cards, it seems unlikely that such a physical DisplayPort (or MHL) path exists from the GPU to the mainboard's USB-C controller.

Even for integrated processor GPUs, there needs to be an additional USB-C controller that negotiates the appropriate alternate mode and physically routes the signals.

The principles are explained in [this presentation](http://www.displayport.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/DP-Alt-Mode-Overview-for-VESA-v1.pdf) of the DisplayPort alternate mode.

If your current hardware doesn't support any USB-C alternate modes out of the box (or is at least prepared for it), I wouldn't expect a software update to be able to change that.