# What options to transport video, USB and power on a single cable?

Tags: usb, hdmi, cable, usb-c

My source does not come with a USB-C port (only USB 2.0 type A, HDMI and DisplayPort). Still, I would like to combine **USB**, **video** and **power** on a **single cable**, in a similar way as USB-C hubs do. I do not need ARC, CEC, Ethernet, and neither USB 3.

[image]

I have been reading about [USB alternate mode](https://superuser.com/questions/964690/what-hardware-support-needs-to-be-present-for-usb-type-c-alternate-modes). It seems to me that all that it does is some wire switching, therefore I have been thinking about getting some breakouts (as the ones below) and solder some wire so that the HDMI, power and USB 2 data can be injected through a single USB-C port, carried over a USB-C cable, and finally separated on the other side.

The HDMI TMDS channels could be switched according to the cable orientation when plugged in, is this a problem? What about different approaches?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not possible with USB 2.0.

Comment: Well, it's possible with a single _cable_... just not with a single USB 2.0 _port._ (Remember e.g. iPod dock connectors?)

Comment: @grawity (and GabrielaGarcia) It seems I didn't explain myself well enough. I do not want to squeeze all that data through a USB 2 port, but through a USB-C port. Please consider the edit.